# Subtracting Amounts from Specific Categories

Tags: formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm working on trying to make a relatively simple spending tracker using Google Sheets. In this example, the person has $5000 already in the bank, and they have earned $1000. The categories of Housing, Transport, Food, and Commodities are the different types of purchases that this person makes. My goal for this spreadsheet would be to go to column I, choose one of the designations from the drop-down menu (Housing, Transport, Food, Commodities), and have the amount of that purchase be subtracted from the corresponding budget. For example, if a Housing-related purchase of $50 was made, $50 would then be subtracted from cell H2 (The Housing Budget), and the number displayed would go from $300 to $250. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. :)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f8Z3zUt7Yqnr-39Kqi7xFpAEJsdkviVya3EQtt4QTLs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your spreadsheet is protected however this should be an application of SUMIF.  The most important part is how to t6otal up all entries by category (or date) etc.  That is shown below.

#### Example

- **`formula`** (F2)
  =SUMIF(`range`,‎ `criterion`,‎ [`sum_range`])
  =SUMIF(B:B, E2, C:C)
  =$170
- **`range`**
  =column with category tags
  =B:B
- **`criterion`**
  =category by which to SUMIF
  =E2
  ="Food"
- **`sum_range`**
  =C:C

```
       A        B        C    D    E       F
--+--------+---------+-------+-+--------+--------------------+-
1 | Date   |Category | Spent | | SUM By | TOTAL              |
--+--------+---------+-------+-+--------+--------------------+-
2 | 1/1/22 | Food    | $120  | | Food   | =SUMIF(B:B,E2,C:C) |
--+--------+---------+-------+-+--------+--------------------+-
3 | 1/2/22 | Housing | $175  | |        |                    |
--+--------+---------+-------+-+--------+--------------------+-
4 | 1/3/22 | Food    | $ 50  | |        |                    |
--+--------+---------+-------+-+--------+--------------------+-
5 | 1/2/22 | Housing | $300  | |        |                    |
--+--------+---------+-------+-+--------+--------------------+-
```